# Which preposition to use with "interface"

Tags: prepositions

What is the best preposition **at/for/on** to use in sentences like these:

```
Configure CoS queue parameters at interface
```

or

```
Configure CoS queue parameters for interface
```

or

```
Configure CoS queue parameters on interface
```

These sentence fragments are help messages for CLI commands in the networking device. Articles are intentionally omitted to shorten them.

**UPDATE #1:**

What should the prepositions be if I use **Set** and **Enable** instead of **Configure**?

```
Enable 'something' on interface
```

and

```
Set 'something' on interface
```

**UPDATE #2:**

Meaning of these fragments is the following:
There is a device and it has some ports (I call them interfaces). There are some parameters that can be **configured** for the particular interface. There are some parameters that can be **enabled** on the interface. There are some attributes that can be **set** on the interface.

Comment: All of these are sentence fragments. What is the full intended usage of any of these?

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Then what do you mean by "interface" here? Do you mean interface as a coding construct, or something involving a user interaction, or possibly something else? This really needs context.

Comment: @Robusto, in my case interface means Ethernet port

Comment: **Different prepositions change the meaning.** You must say what you intend the sentence [fragment] to **mean** in order to determine which preposition gives that meaning.

Comment: @Konstantin: In that case, Ian MacDonald's suggestion below is probably right. I would include the article in that case, to make it sound more comfortable to the ear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an (ex) network engineer, I would use *on* for the "enable" case, and generally use *for* in the "QoS parameters" case.

The rationale is that in the former I am performing an action directly *on* the interface, but in the latter I am performing actions on *settings of* the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the three suggestions you provide, *for* is the word that best describes your meaning.

```
Configure CoS queue parameters for interface
[Use this option to] configure CoS queue parameters for [the] interface[.]
```

However, because the parameters belong to the interface, it might also be appropriate to say:

```
Configure interface CoS queue parameters
[Use this option to] configure [the] interface['s] CoS queue parameters[.]
```

Additionally, if your help message will always apply to a CLI, *interface* might be redundant.

```
Configure CoS queue parameters
[Use this option to] configure CoS queue parameters[.]
```

Comment: Ian, thank you for the reply. In my case the interface word isn't redundant because there are some global settings and some setting for the particular interface.

Comment: Is the interface to CoS generally (and queue parameters are set there), or just to managing the CoS queue in particular? Respectively, would “Configure CoS interface queue parameters”, or “Configure CoS queue interface parameters”, be clear to your users?